# Why this complex delete SQL query is not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am trying to implement a "complex" SQL delete query but it is not working.

This is my query:

```
DELETE
FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series     AS MC_PS
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD
      ON MC_PS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id 
INNER JOIN MarketDetails                     AS MD
      ON  MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id  
WHERE
      MD.localization_id = 1
```

I want to delete all the rows only from the **Market_Commodity_Price_Series** but with this WHERE condition. As you can see the where condition use some JOIN operation.

The problem is that performing this query I am obtaining this error message:

> #42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS MC_PS INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD       ON MC_PS.mar' at line 2

How can I fix this? Maybe using this as sub query:

```
SELECT MC_PS.id
FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series     AS MC_PS
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD
      ON MC_PS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id 
INNER JOIN MarketDetails                     AS MD
      ON  MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id  
WHERE
      MD.localization_id = 1
```

(using the ID)

but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to delete MC_PS so write it after delete "MC_PS" which is missing

```
DELETE MC_PS
FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series     AS MC_PS
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD
      ON MC_PS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id 
INNER JOIN MarketDetails                     AS MD
      ON  MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id  
WHERE
      MD.localization_id = 1
```